# I am unable to load Image from SD card to ImageView in android studio

Tags: java, android

```
imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
String pathName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/person.png";
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see if your app has permission to read from external storage i.e. `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

```
String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/abc.jpg";
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1 );
```

Comment: yes..I gave the permission and typed the same code. but still it is showing white screen while opening...........<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>